# TLauncher ubuntu 22.04 fresh install no sound

Tags: ubuntu, audio, minecraft

So, when I start minecraft via TLauncher there is no sound, despite my sound card is detected in sound settings.

I tried starting it with padsp but in logs it tells me that it is missing a lib file.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/\22926LIB/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to find an actual path to "libpulsedsp.so". Try editing binary padsp:

With your text editor edit file /usr/bin/padsp and change this:

```
if [ x"$LD_PRELOAD" = x ] ; then
   LD_PRELOAD="/usr/\\$$LIB/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so"
else
   LD_PRELOAD="$LD_PRELOAD /usr/\\$$LIB/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so"
fi
```

to

```
LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so"
```

and check if there is actually file to "libpulsedsp.so"